# SQL Server Agent - sending emails with no content

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a query below which tells me if something is due in the next 24 hours, however using SQL Server Agent, it sends an email whether the query returns a result or not, so:

**My Question**

based on the SQL Code below which I will add directly into an SQL Agent Job, can i set it up to not send an email of the query returns a 0 row count?

I have done some research however applying a boolean doesnt work to detect if there are results or not, or I may have done it wrong:

**Code**

```
DECLARE @xml NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @body NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @xml = CAST(( 

SELECT 
Jobs.JobID AS 'td', '' ,
Jobs.JobName AS 'td', '',
ToDoList.List AS 'td', '', 
Staff.StaffName AS 'td', '',
CONVERT(DATE, ToDoItem.DueDate)  AS 'td', '',
ToDoItem.Comment  AS 'td', ''

FROM ToDoItem 
INNER JOIN Staff ON ToDoList.StaffID= Staff.StaffID
INNER JOIN ToDoList on ToDoItem.ToDoListID = ToDoList.ToDoListID
INNER JOIN JobSummaryAndStatus ON ToDoList.JSASID = JobSummaryAndStatus.JSASID
INNER JOIN Jobs ON ProjectSummaryAndStatus.JobID= Jobs.JobID

WHERE DueDate BETWEEN GETDATE() AND GETDATE() + 1
AND Staff.StaffID = 20

FOR XML PATH('tr'), ELEMENTS ) AS NVARCHAR(MAX))


SET @body ='<html><body><H3>Jobs Due Today</H3>
<table border = 1> 
<tr>
<th> Job Ref </th> <th> JobName </th> <th> List Name </th> <th> Staff Name </th> <th> Due Date </th> <th> Comments </th></tr>'    

SET @body = @body + @xml +'</table></body></html>'


EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
@body = @body,
@body_format ='HTML',
@recipients = 'myemail@domain.com;',
@subject = 'Jobs Due Today';
```

**Research**

I tried this with little success so hopefully its my SQL Knowledge which is the reason why i cant apply this simple boolean checker. Im sure it would check the @body tag at the bottom before it sends the email and I could and in a IF statement of sorts here

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic1131198-391-1.aspx

thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there isn't any result from the query the `@xml` variable should be empty so you should be able to check that:

```
if (len(@xml) > 0)
    begin
       EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
       @body = @body,
       @body_format ='HTML',
       @recipients = 'myemail@domain.com;',
       @subject = 'Jobs Due Today';
    end
```

I haven't tried it though.

Comment: im checking the wrong one, at least it was a simple mistake and i understand, cheers